# NSwag MSBuild Specification Generation in .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: .net, .net-4.8, nswag, nswagstudio

I have a project built in .Net Framework 4.8, i have implemented NSwag, decorated postprocess with basic stuff, such as title, version, description, added few extensions, and made it serve openapi-v3 version(since it serves swagger 2.0  by default in .net 4.8). this is all great. but the problem arises when i want to produce open-api sppecification on build time with Nswag.MSBuild since it does not look at post-process at all.

Is there anyway to decorate openapi specification produced by [NSwag.MSbuild](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag.MSBuild)?

I assume it could be done if I could reference [DocumentProcessor](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors) into [nswag.json](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag-Configuration-Document), the documentation says that NSwag studio can generate "nswag.json" but I have not found a way.

Any help would be appreciated.